# Is there a way to shorten this json code with TypeError exceptions?

Tags: python-3.x

Hello im trying to get this code to work and output nicknames from a json list, but some of them are null ('nickname' object doesnt exits on the 'profiles' array) but I still need them to be output as None and not simply supress. This code I wrote works but I have to do it 27 more times and it would become huge and is there a way to shorten it?

data is a JSON array, example

```
[{"nickname": "Ana", "id": 0}, {"nickname": "Sofia", "id": 1}, {"nickname": null, "id": 2}]
```

```py
def userProfileList(self, data):
    self.json = data

    nicknames = []
    for obj in data:
        try: nickname = obj['nickname']
        except TypeError: nickname = None
        nicknames.append(nickname)

    self.nickname = nicknames
```

Comment: What do you mean by you'll have to do it 27 more times? If your code works, what's the problem?

Comment: My question wasn't why doesn't it work but if there was a way to make it in one line of code or shorten it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your JSON object contains 'null', which isn't a keyword in Python, I'll assume that you're getting it from an external source and so I'll also assume that you're parsing it with the [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) function, which will automatically turn `null` into `None`.

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to generate the list of nicknames:

```py
nicknames = [index['nickname'] for index in data]
```

Example

```py
import json
raw = '[{"nickname": "Ana", "id": 0}, {"nickname": "Sofia", "id": 1}, {"nickname": null, "id": 2}]'
data = json.loads(raw)
nicknames = [index['nickname'] for index in data]
print(nicknames)
```

Returns `['Ana', 'Sofia', None]`

Comment: I get this error:


`self.nickname = [x['nickname'] for x in data]`
`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: I can't help without more info; edit your original question with the most recent code (keeping [Minimal, Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in mind)